# Getting error with angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm doing a Rails 5 application.
I have a simple code for showing sign-in page.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']).config([
    '$stateProvider',
    '$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
        .state('sign_in', {
          url: '/sign_in',
          templateUrl: '/angular_views/sign_in.html',
          controller: 'SignInController'
        })

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('sign_in');
  }])
```

I'm getting error logs in browser.

```
Error: transition superseded
Error: transition prevented
Error: transition aborted
```

This is my angular-ui-router version

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

angular-ui-router-rails (0.2.15)
```

It seems the latest version available:

```
$ gem update angular-ui-router-rails
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
```

Please help how to fix it.

Comment: mmm ..can you post also your index.htmlm with the files that you're including?

Comment: Which version of ui-router do you have installed? Upgrading ui-router to the latest version should fix this.

Comment: Take a look here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/3246

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your Angular-UI-Router version.Upgrade your UI-Router and give a try